# Loop form fields in PHP

Tags: php, forms, loops, post, foreach

I need to loop through _POST form fields. The problem is that I don't know how much fields there are and what their names are. I need to access their name value and type.
Tried lots of things, without any success...

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?  Can you show `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: post what you have tried.

Comment: There is no way to determine the input type from the `$_POST` value without passing it through the form in another value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a foreach loop and then use gettype of the value to determine what the type is.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $type = gettype($value);
}
```

Although, I think gettype will probably return string for everything. Php is not a strongly typed language.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
// Do whatever you would like to do with $key and $val
}
```